# jQuery UI-Datepicker disable all Sundays EXCEPT 1 specific Sunday

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

With the jQuery UI-Datepicker you can disable specific days. In my case I disable all Sundays, Mondays and Tuesdays. That works great. But I want to add 1 exception. 1 specific Sunday must be enabled: Sunday 10 May 2020. I couldn't find out anywhere how to achive this.

```
beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var day = d.getDay();
    return [(day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2)];
}
```